# Filtering large vcf file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a VCF file with following format:

| #CHROM | POS | ID | REF | ALT | QUAL | FILTER. | INFO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 10061 | . | A | T | 77.1 | AC0 | AC=2;AN=53780 |
| chr1 | 10162 | . | A | GC | 81.0. | AC0;AS_VQSR | AC=1;AN=3615 |

I want to apply couple of filters:

1. Retain only those rows where length of REF and ALT column is exactly 1.
2. After first filter I want to keep keep those cells where AC (look at INFO) column should be above a certain threshold.
3. Finally remove duplicates based on chr1 and Pos whereby I retain the row with highest quality (QUAL column).

So the output would look like if threshold for AC was 2 or more:

| #CHROM | POS | ID | REF | ALT | QUAL | FILTER. | INFO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 10061 | . | A | T | 77.1 | AC0 | AC=2;AN=53780 |

It is a big compressed file with more than 845923625 lines. I was thinking of reading it via pandas because it is tab deliminated. So can someone assist me with the most efficient way to filter this file. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

With the following toy dataframe mimicking yours:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "#CHROM": ["chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr1"],
        "POS": [10061, 10162, 10163, 10061],
        "ID": [".", ".", ".", "."],
        "REF": ["A", "A", "AA", "A"],
        "ALT": ["T", "GC", "Y", "Z"],
        "QUAL": ["77.1", "81.0.", "80.0", "63.0"],
        "FILTER.": ["AC0", "AC0;AS_VQSR", "AC1", "AC2"],
        "INFO": ["AC=2;AN=53780", "AC=1;AN=3615", "AC=0;AN=3615", "AC=2;AN=3615"],
    }
)

print(df)
# Output
  #CHROM    POS ID REF ALT   QUAL      FILTER.           INFO
0   chr1  10061  .   A   T   77.1          AC0  AC=2;AN=53780
1   chr1  10162  .   A  GC  81.0.  AC0;AS_VQSR   AC=1;AN=3615
2   chr2  10163  .  AA   Y   80.0          AC1   AC=0;AN=3615
3   chr1  10061  .   A   Z   63.0          AC2   AC=2;AN=3615
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
df = (
    df.loc[
        (df["REF"].str.len() == 1)
        & (df["ALT"].str.len() == 1)
        & (int(df["INFO"].values[0][3]) >= 2),
        :,
    ]
    .sort_values(by="QUAL", ascending=False)
    .drop_duplicates(subset=["#CHROM", "POS"], keep="first")
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
  #CHROM    POS ID REF ALT  QUAL FILTER.           INFO
0   chr1  10061  .   A   T  77.1     AC0  AC=2;AN=53780
```